# Random curved movements for gained bonus objects

Tags: actionscript-3, math, spline

I am trying to create random curved movements like a gliding bird or some flying "gained bonus" objects. This is a very familiar movement from nearly all mobile games.

All bonus objects moves from character/object to its resting point on the screen. All sample bonus movements follows random curved orbits. Like parabola or spline I don't know exactly. Also bird movie clips flies on a series of curved track.

Anybody know the way to simulate such movement as given examples above?

**I've tried** : 
I searched online and then I've tried with `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` functions. I managed to produce only circular movement. But I need random radius and center point of curves. 
Thanks already..

Comment: Maybe you want a **tweening** utility (where you tell it your x/y destination pos and it will auto move the object to that position)? Try this **[visual demo](http://greensock.com/ease-visualizer)** from Greensock. Maybe you can download and test it for moving your "bonus amount" text or sprites?. If it's not right then, you need to show us a visual example (some Youtube link) of what **exactly** you need to achieve.

Comment: Sory for my poor English and all my grammer mistakes. I need like these:
Collcetion of bonnus objects like stars, coins etc:
https://youtu.be/yWo87nOlWUU
 and 
Random bird orbit:
https://youtu.be/tdZmGTwcGXY

Comment: @ErkanÇamyar thank you for providing examples, however, the two examples provided are very different. The motion of the bird has no end, whereas the bonus points go from one starting point to one end point. What are you really looking for? Asking for "random movement" in general is too broad. Please clarify or ask two separate questions if you want to know how to achieve both.

Comment: Thanks @null and Sory for my English again :) no i need them separetely. Not both. I coldnt achieve simulating of curved paths like them. Bonnus objects' path starting from any point to collection point. How can i apply for each bonnus objects? Another problem is about my second example video. Continious and random curved path tracking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a subclass of Hermite Spline called the Catmull-Rom Spline. It's useful for games because you don't need to calculate control points; you just give any number of waypoints (ie, some semi-random points between your object and its destination) and a Catmull-Rom Spline will smoothly fit through all of them.

An ActionScript version of the algorithm can be found here:
http://flashcove.net/795/cubic-spline-generation-in-as3-catmull-rom-curves/